# Correct way to handle multilple buttons on Begin Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Would like to ask whether this way is correct or not to call two actions in a begin form

This works fine for me,would like to know whether this is the correct way or not.

I have added formaction="/Controller/Action" in button.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

<input type="submit" value="Update" id="btnSubmit" />

<input type="submit" value="Reset" formaction="/Home/Reset" id="btnReset"/>
}
```

Comment: What is you `Reset()` method doing? Do you really need do a POST as opposed to a simple redirect?

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: Reset will clear all the textbox.                                                          public ActionResult Reset(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                ModelState.Clear();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

Comment: Can you help me out with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483191/retain-image-on-view-before-submit-returns-null-on-submit